# convert rownames to column format in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe where the row names need to be the first column and assigned a header. I would prefer not to use any packages, just base functions in R. Hoping for a one liner.

Input:

```
             V1
Species1     31.76010
Species2     43.97335
Species3     40.29958
```

Desired output:

```
HeaderName   V1
Species1     31.76010
Species2     43.97335
Species3     40.29958
```

Comment: If that Input is a dataframe named dfrm It would just be `cbind(Header=rownames(dfrm), dfrm)`

Comment: `df <- data.frame(names = row.names(df), df);`
`rownames(df) <- NULL`

Comment: How would I undue that i.e. so the column goes back to row names with header removed?

Comment: `tibble::rownames_to_column(df, var = "HeaderName")`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `df$HeaderName <- row.names(df)` to assign your row indexes to a column HeaderName

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please [edit] your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22039826)